# Angular 2 currency pipe doesn't work in chrome Version 34.0.1847.131 m

Tags: angular

Here is my code. credit.creditSum - this is number I'm sure. I tried this in firefox and it works. But in chrome not.

```
<div *ngIf="credit" class="row">
    <div class="span-12">
      <!-- table content 1 -->
      <div class="head_1">
        <span class="title_1">{{credit.id}}</span>
        <span class="title_summ">{{credit.creditSum | currency:'USD':true}}</span>
        <span class="title_ccy">EUR</span>
      </div>
      <!-- end table content 1 -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is an error

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: length in [{{credit.creditSum | currency:'USD':true}} in CreditDetailsComponent@25:33] browser_adapter.ts:73
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: length browser_adapter.ts:73
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: browser_adapter.ts:73
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: length
    at defineProperty (native)
```

Comment: I guess you need to provide more information.

Comment: I tried the my Plunker in Chrome.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is it work in chrome? I also tried your example - the same issue. Looks like my browser problem.

Comment: Yup, I only have Chrome (Version 49.0.2623.56 beta (64-bit)) installed yet on my new machine.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/DfiZubmdsh5eaI6rkCGy?p=preview
The error is obviously not with the currency pipe.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

<span class="title_summ">{{credit.creditSum | currency:'USD':true}}</span>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  credit = {creditSum: 10};
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Comment: Strange. I tried the same implementation. Doesn't work. Shows the same error. I used 2.0.0-beta.6 version.

Comment: Ok so it seems that the relevant question is: "What polyfill makes this work?"